# C# using my own C++/CLI DLL: Error: 'mytrainOp' is not supported by the language

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, mixed-mode

My C++ class has only one method:

```
string MyThreadsCpp::MyThreadsCppClass::train(){

    double sum = 0.0;
    long max = 100 * 1000;
    int perc = 0;;

    for (long n = 0; n < max; n++){
        sum += 4.0*pow(-1.0, n) / (2 * n + 1.0);
        int rem = n % (max/10);
        if (rem == 0){
            perc = 100 * n / max;
            cout << perc << "%" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "100%" << endl;
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Result = " << sum;
    return oss.str();
}
```

It works fine.

C++/CLI class Library for this also has only one method:

```
string ThreadsCppWrapper::ThreadsCppWrapperClass::mytrainOp(int% i){
    i++;
        return ptr->train();
}
```

It builds fine.

C# code consuming this DLL:

```
namespace ThreadsCsharp
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
       private void btnTrain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadsCppWrapperClass obj = new ThreadsCppWrapperClass();
            int i = 5;
            obj.mytrainOp(i); /* This is where I get Error */
        }
    }
}
```

Intellisense Errors for the above line:
Error   1
    No overload for method 'mytrainOp' takes 1 arguments
Error   2
    Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

Experts, Please help.

Comment: Call it with `ref`, i.e. `obj.mytrainOp(ref i);`

Comment: Also, you can't just read an `std::string` from C#, you'll have to return a `System::String^`, so return `msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(ptr->train())` instead (needs `#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>`) - see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, dbc abd Lucas

Answer (score 2):

It is not a great error message, the C# compiler struggles mightily when trying to figure out what to do with the `std::string` object you return.  Also well hidden in your C# program since you don't actually use it.  That doesn't matter, the compiler still needs to deal with it.

You must return a managed string instead, like this:

```
String^ ThreadsCppWrapper::ThreadsCppWrapperClass::mytrainOp(int% i){
    i++;
    return gcnew String(ptr->train().c_cstr());
}
```

And of course if you don't actually have a use for that string then just declare the return value type as `void`.  Next error you get is the one that reminds you to pass the argument with `ref`, you can figure that one out.

Comment: Please help on coupled question.. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458544/c-cli-to-c-error-s-incompatible-with-void-stdcall-int-i-stdstring)

Comment: You are casting to the wrong type.  You need to cast to the native function pointer type, not the managed delegate type.  Fall in the pit of success by writing a `typedef` for the native function pointer type.  Please close your question.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: I really did not get you. I need to create a delegate in c#, pass it it c++/cli function which is ok. Now I need to again pass this delegate as a function pointer as a parameter to native class function. Now can you help?